# How to use Xcode auto layout in this case?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have tried to use auto layout with this UIImage View and Text View, I have added the 4 Pins but it seems thats not enough constraints because its not fitted well on these screens (3.5" , 4" , 4.7")

so what I should add to make it fit as the image below ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select left, right & top pins and height checkbox of imageview and add constraints. Now select textview and give all four side constraints.